# dplyr select column when column name is number

Tags: r, select, dplyr, pipeline

I want to reshape the data and then select a specific column.

```
data(ChickWeight)
chick <- ChickWeight %>% spread(Time,weight) %>% filter(Diet=="1")
```

It creates the column names for me, which are numbers. So how could I select the column that named "0"? I know that `%>% select(3)` may work, but I need the solution to select columns with their names being number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use backticks to select columns with their names being number

```
data(ChickWeight)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
chick <- ChickWeight %>% spread(Time,weight) %>% filter(Diet==2) %>% select(`0`)
```

Comment: Your answer essentially was correct. It probably was downvoted - I corrected this - because you did not test your answer (there is no `0`), and the recommended way is to make the question/answer self-contained.